# Regex that removes everything but the number

Tags: java, regex, string, pdf

I am trying to use java's `string.replaceAll()` or `replaceFirst()` method in order to edit data read from a pdf document. A line of data that could be returned is:

21/1**E (6-11) 4479 77000327633 (U)

I wish to only store the `77000327633` into a variable for working with and looking for the correct regex that will capture ONLY this 11 digit number.  I've tried searching around for a regex but nothing seems to give me my desired outcome.

Comment: Is the structure always the same? Which expressions did you try so far? If you can provide an expression that matches the number you could wrap the number part in a capturing group and use a back reference in `replaceAll()`, e.g. `"yourstring".replaceAll("prefix(number)suffix","$1")`.

Comment: if you know that the number is always about 11 digit you can simple use this regex (\d{5,11})  here you can test https://regex101.com/r/kT3rR0/1

Comment: What is the rule for choosing the number? The last number in the string? The largest number in the string? Any number with more than four digits? The fourth non-space entry in the string? What?

Comment: @giuseppestraziota I understand that part, but if I were to use that in replaceFirst or replaceAll it'd only remove that number where I want the opposite.

Comment: ok, you can use this https://regex101.com/r/kT3rR0/2 and replace with $2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
String value = "21/1**E (6-11) 4479 77000327633 (U)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".* (\\d{11}) .*");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("$1"));
```

**Output:**

```
77000327633
```

**NB:** This assumes that your number has 11 digits and that there is a space before and after.

**NB2:** It is not meant to be perfect it is only to show the idea which is here to define a global pattern with a group and replace everything by the content of the group

Answer (score 0):

This is it : `(.*)[ ]([0-9])*[ ](.*)`

Can access to your value using $2

Comment: Looks like you misplaced the quantifier.

Comment: what do you mean ?